# Couldn't save simple jmeter file

Tags: jmeter

This is what always pop-up every time I attempt to save a JMeter file.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have write rights on the folder where you are trying to write the file.

Also in your question show the jmeter.log output and the popup as screenshot so that we can give you more details